# Convert a currency string to a number Drupal Views / PHP

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, view, drupal-views

I am feeding a field from a CiviCRM (MySQL) database into a Drupal View of a currency:

```
€ 350.00
```

**How can I get this currency / string into number format to perform maths on it?**

I've tried

- removing that field from the display and feeding it into a Global Maths Field in order to "clean" it but it just shows up as zero (it is a string so the Maths Field cannot read it)
- feeding it into a Global Text Field results in the same output as above
- turning off all formatting in the field itself and in the Global Maths Field I was feeding it into, which outputs zero because it still is not recognized as a number

Comment: Removing unnecessary text helps the reader, make the question come out clearly, grouped the tries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 steps:

1. Install [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) (7.x-2.x-dev) - that will give you a Global
   PHP field in Views
2. Exclude the original field (say `field_currency`) which is holding the value from display in Views (using tickbox), and then use the value of the excluded field in additional PHP field:

   - In Value code: `preg_match("#([0-9\.]+)#", $row->field_currency, $match); return $match[0];`
   - In Output code: `<?php echo $value; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function like this:

```
function extractNumber($str) {
  return preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/i','',$str);
}

echo extractNumber('€ 350.00');
```

Which will result in: '350.00' which is numeric. and for '€ 1,350.00' it will return '1350.00'.